# Why this code became infinite loop when entering floating number?

Tags: c++

**Program to take negative input**
This program works perfectly with int but when inputting float it become infinite loop.
why ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

     int positive = 0;
     
     while(positive>=0){
          cout<<"Enter number"; cin>> positive;
          if (positive<0){
               cout<<"yes it is negative";
          }
     }
     
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What number did you enter? Have you considered adding error checking to the input? Once the stream goes bad because `.` is not an int it won't read again unless you clear the error and ignore the invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Because C++ is a typed language and it can't accept a float value into int variable without conversion.

How to fix it?

```
    cin >> positive;

    if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    }
```

One way is to add an error check.
But I'd argue a better way is to just use float variable (error checking is still useful)
TL;DR Change int positive to float